# What is the difference between running npm dedupe in npm2 versus using npm3?

Tags: npm

In npm3, it tries to install dependancies in a maximally flat way. But in npm2, we already have the `npm dedupe` command which seems to also flatten dependancies. If I am already doing `npm dedupe` with npm2, is there any advantage to using npm3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and installed `npm3` and it turns out that it seems there is no difference between the two in terms of the `dedupe` command. The main difference is that when modules are installed in `npm3`, they will tend to be installed "flat", whereas in `npm2` and earlier, they will go below the dependent module in a `node_modules` directory.

An series of illustrative ASCII diagrams follow.

In `npm2` (module A depends on B and C, which both depend on D):

```
+----A----B----D
        |
        \
         -C----D
```

After `dedupe` in both `npm2` and `npm3`, D is moved up to the top level:

```
+----A----B
     |  |
     |  \
     |   -C
     D
```

In `npm3`, after `npm install`, we will see that B and C are also moved up to the top level:

```
+----A
     |
     |
     |
     D
     |
     |
     |
     B
     |
     |
     |
     C
```